# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space looping inside table on Postgresql using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The problem is obvious, but I can't find a solution to this...

I'm migrating 700k of data inside postgresql table to an API.

To do that, I have created the following

```
    List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.setPagination(new Pagination());
      do {
         list = myData.find(filter);
         //code that sends this data to the API 
         //out of scope of the problem
       } while(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list));
```

I'm using Hibernate to query this data, like below:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Mensagem> myData(Filter filter {

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyData.class);

    if (filter.getPagination().getQuantity() <= 0) {
        filter.getPagination().setQuantity(countMyData());
    }

    dealWithPagination(filter, criteria);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

The problem is everytime I loop inside the do/while all the objects of mydata is allocated inside the heap.

What should I do to Garbage Collect this objects? Because it seems that while the do/while do not finish, the objects are not collected.

Any clues?

Comment: Where are you opening / closing the transaction ? All entities loaded by hibernate will be put in the session (unless you use a Stateless Session, or evict them for the session manually), and not be gc until the session is closed, which happen when the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: That is it! The entities were in the session. The transaction was not being closed, causing the outofmemory